# QTP-Cannot find Object property

Tags: qtp

I am a beginner in QTP.I want to add objects locally to local repository for automating the google search page.When I tried to add objects to local repository using "Add objects to local" option it is showing as "Window - Google Chrome" object instead of "Browser:Page hierarchy".I started my browser from C drive only.I dont know why happening like this.Because of this I could not automate it and getting error Cannot find WebEdit parent properties like this...Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, the web support isn't loaded.
This could ocour because of several things:

1. You should open the browser only **after QTP/UFT is running** (opening the browser before QTP/UFT could lead to the effect you described)
2. If you are working on Chrome, see that the QTP/UFT extension is enabled (navigate to chrome://extensions/, and enable the QTP/UFT extension)
3. If you are working on FireFox, see that the QTP/UFT extension is enabled (you can find it in Tools menu->Add-ons->Extensions)